# Class design patterns - best practices

Tags: php, class, design-patterns

men and women!

My problem is I don't really know what is the best way to design so I defined 2 classes 1'st one is:

```
class color
{
  private $id = NULL; 
  private $name = '';
  private $rgb = NULL; 
  private $cmy = NULL;
  private $wavelength = NULL; 
  private $frequency = NULL; 

public function __construct($name, $rgb, $cmy, $wavelenght, $frequency)
{
    setName($name);
    setRGB($rgb);
    setCMY($cmy);
    setWavelength($wavelength);
    setFrequency($frequency);
}

public function __destruct()
{

}

public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name=$name;
}

public function setRGB($rgb)
{
    $this->rgb=$rgb;
}

public function setCMY($cmy)
{
    $this->cmy=$cmy;
}

public function setWavelength($wavelength)
{
    $this->wavelength=$wavelength;
}

public function setFrequency($frequency)
{
    $this->frequency=$frequency;
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function getRGB()
{
    return $this->rgb;
}

public function getCMY()
{
    return $this->cmy;
}

public function getWavelength()
{
    return $this->wavelength;
}

public function getFrequency()
{
    return $this->frequency;
}

public function toJSON()
{
    return "{'id':'".$this->id."', 'name':'".$this->name."', 'rgb':'".$this->rgb."', 'cmy':'".$this->cmy."', 'wavelength':'".$this->wavelength."', 'frequency':'".$this->frequency."'}";
}

public function toCSV()
{
    return $this->id . ", " . $this->name . ", " . $this->rgb . ", " . $this->cmy . ", " . $this->wavelength . ", " . $this->frequency;
}

public function toHTML()
{
    return "<p>ID: " . $this->id . "</p><p>Name: " . $this->name . "</p><p>RGB: " . $this->rgb . "</p><p>CMY: " . $this->cmy . "</p><p>Wavelength: " . $this->wavelength . "</p><p>Frequency: " . $this->frequency . "</p>";
}
```

and 2'nd class looks like

```
class CRUD_color
{
    public function create_color($parameters)
    {
       $color=new color();
       $color->setName($parameter['name']);
       $color->setRGB($parameter['rgb']);
       $color->setCMY($parameter['cmy']);
       $color->setWavelength($parameter['wavelength']);
       $color->setFrequency($parameter['frequency']);

       $entitymanager->persist($color);
       $entitymanager->flush();
    }
    public function request_color($parameters)
    {
       $color=$entitymanager->find($parameter['id']);
       echo $color->toJSON($parameter['name']);
    }
    public function update_color($parameters)
    {
       $color=$entitymanager->find($parameter['id']);
       $color->setName($parameter['name']);
       $color->setRGB($parameter['rgb']);
       $color->setCMY($parameter['cmy']);
       $color->setWavelength($parameter['wavelength']);
       $color->setFrequency($parameter['frequency']);

       $entitymanager->persist($color);
       $entitymanager->flush();
    }
    public function delete_color($parameters)
    {
       $color=$entitymanager->delete($parameter['id']);
    }
}
```

now my question is if maybe it is better to have only one class color and include the functions from the second class in the 1st one? or let them apart?

why is one better than the other or vice versa? the design pattern is important to me  so why choose one over the other..

Is there a problem if lets say we have the function create_color in witch we instantianate the class itself like new color() ????

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You know that instead of `private $id = NULL; 
private $name = '';
private $rgb = NULL; 
private $cmy = NULL;` etc you can simply do:
`private $id = NULL, 
$name = '',
$rgb = NULL, 
$cmy = NULL,` etc

Comment: Design is always subjective. Best or worst depends on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now my question is if maybe it is better to have only one class color
>   and include the functions from the second class in the 1st one?

No.

> or let them apart?

Yes.

> why is one better than the other or vice versa?

If you decide to have different types of CRUDs or other objects that manipulate with colors (Builder for example) you need class Color to be a separate one. The same if you would like your CRUD to manipulate not only with Color objects. It is better to make decoupling as much as possible.

> the design pattern is important to me so why choose one over the
>   other..

There are many patterns that can be helpful for you: Builder, Repository, Decorator, Bridge, Factory... It depends on your needs what is better to implement. You must be familiar with all of them and never implement it without understanding of why it is best choice for this particular task.

> Is there a problem if lets say we have the function create_color in
>   witch we instantianate the class itself like new color() ????

Yes, if you need to add some creational step (for example generate ID in different way) you have to add this step to all your classes like Color, Font etc. In case of separate builder class - you add this step to create() method and it will generate ID in new way for all abstract objects.

Hope this will show you a way to learn more about patterns. Good luck!

BTW, take a look at this great free book: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/